# Compact subgroups of a linear group over non-Archimedean local field

Tags: gr.group-theory, topological-groups, p-adic-groups, local-fields, p-adic-numbers

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a non-Archimedean local field. Let $\mathcal{O}$ be its ring of integers.

**Is it true that any compact subgroup of $\GL_n(\mathbb{F})$ is conjugated to a subgroup of $\GL_n(\mathcal{O})$?** A reference would be very helpful.

Comment: For the field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ I saw this statement as an exercise [here](https://www.math.toronto.edu/~herzig/MAT1104-exercises.pdf), Exercise 1. I think the reasoning there holds for any finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Answer (score 3):

The group $G={\rm GL}(n,F)$ acts transitively on $\mathcal O$-lattices of $F^n$. The stabilizer  of the standard lattice $L_o = {\mathcal O}^n$ is $K={\rm GL}({\mathcal O})$. It is an open compact subgroup of $G$.

Let $K'$ be any compact subgroup of $G$. It stabilizes the set
$$
L= \sum_{g\in K'} g.L_o =\sum_{g\in K'/K'\cap K} g.L_o \ .
$$
The set $L$ is a lattice as finite sum of lattices. Indeed the quotient $K'/K'\cap K$ is finite since $K'\cap K$ is open in $K'$.

Writing $L=gL_o$, for some $g\in G$,  we obtain that $K'$ is contained in $gKg^{-1}$. This proves that any maximal compact subgroup of $G$ is a conjugate of $K$.

For basic facts on lattices you can check the first chapter of A. Weil's Basic Number Theory.